# How to read the urls and html components used in the selenium test case

Tags: java, selenium

my selenium test code looks like below.

```
@Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSeleJunit() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Item")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("name")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("i18n1");
    driver.findElement(By.name("mode")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ok-button")).click();
}
```

From java code how can i get the url and the locators for which the test case is written?

Comment: My goal is to find the missing selenium test case based on url. first i got the list of urls for a single main url(like http://google.com) using jsoup. Now i need to get the urls from the selenium test programatically and compare these urls to check whether testcase for that particular url exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get current url please use the following code

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

I am realy sure this is what you asked for ,if this is not what you asked for please explain your problem bit more